# Infinitely nested ng-repeat in an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object containing infinitely nested data, like the following example:

```
[
{
    name: "Foo",
    value: "Bar",
    sub: [
        {
            name: "ABC",
            value: "LLL",
            sub: [
                ...
            ]
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: "Oof",
    value: "Rab"
    sub: [
        ...
    ]
}
]
```

Every element can contain a `sub` value, which would contain one or multiple elements with the same structure (`name`, `value`, `sub` if there are more sub-elements).

Now, I know how to do a `ng-repeat`, but with a single `ng-repeat`, I'll get only the elements from the first level. If I did a second `ng-repeat` inside the first one, I'd get only the items from the second level, etc...

As I don't know how many levels there would be, I can't just nest a few `ng-repeat` inside each other. That is why I'm looking for a way to recursively loop over the entire data array and represent all the items that are inside, inside an Angular directive (that is, using Angular's directives/attributes inside my HTML code). Is that possible with Angular (1.3.x) ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by using inline template

Example :

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="namVal">
{{ item.name}}
   <ul ng-if="item.sub">
    <li ng-repeat="item in item.sub" ng-include="'namVal'"></li>
  </ul>
</script>
```

in html

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-include="'namVal'"></li>
</ul>
```

UPDATED using Plunkr example by @alexandernst
http://plnkr.co/edit/dKlrvtYH1IbQXFUEk2Wx?p=preview

Comment: Thank you! Will try right now, I'll accept as an answer in an hours or so, I guess ;)

Comment: Ok, I'm getting an infinite loop at some point. Check this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/PXbEryG50CnT9a4m7Zjf?p=preview   In line 26, if I change `sub.sub` to `item.sub`, it freezes. What am I doing wrong?