# Looking for performance issues in an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I created an Angular directive and now I want to improve the performance when the directive is used with large sets of data.

I used Chrome's timeline tool to monitor what happens when my directive is loaded, but I'm unable to understand what exactly is taking those ~2 seconds because no matter where I click, I see Angular calls.

[image]

I did a [demo in plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/57TQvNsbhk1m22E0gg3D?p=preview) so you can do your own tests.

Quick docs for the directive (check full docs [here](http://alexandernst.github.io/angular-multi-select/), if you need).

```
<div
    angular-multi-select       <---- directive
    selection-mode="single"    <---- single or multi
    input-model="testdata"     <---- data that is going to be rendered
    output-model="output"      <---- array of selected items
    item-label="{{ name }}"    <---- template for each rendered item
    button-template="angular-multi-select-btn-data.htm"   <---- template for the directive itself
    button-label="{{ txt[name] || 'Other' }}"   <----- template for how each selected item should be rendered in the directive dropdown
    tick-property="checked">   <---- property containing the un/checked marker
</div>
```

How can I check what exactly is slowing down my directive?

Comment: ng-includes inside ng-repeat are tends to slow. and may be use debounce on ng-model

Comment: The ng-includes inside ng-repeat is the only way I could find how to make recursive lists (question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367761/infinitely-nested-ng-repeat-in-an-angular-directive). About the debounce, do you mean I should debounce the function that is called when watching the input model? @YOU

Comment: also using function inside expressions are slow because they are called many many times, like, {{ Math.abs(_areAllChecked(filteredModel)) }} , `_getLeafs(outputModel) | filter:search )` , `obj in objs = (_getLeafs(outputModel) | filter:search` instead $watch "search" and make a fixed data.

Comment: yes, ng-include is the only way, but you can write it inline, https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9559, about ng-model debounce - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: @YOU I'm not really sure to understand the inline thing, but my data is dynamic, so I can't "prepare" the nested view. Maybe I'm just not following you. The `ngModelOptions` surely will be helpful.

Comment: this would trigger $digest cycle on every keystroke, `elem.bind('keydown', function(event) {`, if you dont need it, wrap it with debounce/thottle function like lodash have, to run only on some interval like 300ms.

Comment: you can't inline `ng-include src`, but other ng-includes that refer to your own templates can inline. but the downside is, it would complicate simple html to messy and a lot of duplicates. so, its up to you.